# ArrayList initializing as null?

Tags: java, arraylist, null, initialization

Re-asking because my other thread wasn't clear and I didn't understand the true problem.

```
public class Test extends Survey
{
    ArrayList<Answer> answerList;
    ArrayList<Question> questionList;

    public Test()
    {
    questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();
    ...
    }
 ...
}
```

In the eclipse debugger, it's showing `answerList` value as null, while `questionList` is not. What gives?

Edit: Is it possible my debugger is messed up? I can't get it to stop where I'm setting break points. It's stopping at old ones and ignoring new ones. I didn't set up a new configuration or anything.

Comment: Do you re-declare answerList later on?  Where is it showing as null? Can you post an [SSCCE](http:/sscce.org)?

Comment: where is your breakpoint? it makes perfect sense if it's in the line of `answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();`

Comment: There's no issue with that code; you've likely later reinitialized `answerList` as null.

Comment: @onemach has a good point. If your breakpoint is on the initialization line, that line has note yet executed and the value will still be null.

Comment: The breakpoint is after that line is executed, and that's where it's showing as `null`. And no, it is not being reinitialized as `null` later. However, I'm having trouble with the debugger getting to stop at new break points now. Could that be related? I haven't changed configurations or anything, but it's ignoring new breakpoints.

Comment: It may actually be showing the content (is null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your breakpoint on the next line to

```
 answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

And then check answerList.
Because If your breakpoint is on the initialization line, that line has not executed yet and the value will be null at that time.

Comment: Is it possible my debugger is messed up? I can't get it to stop where I'm setting break points. It's stopping at old ones and ignoring new ones. I didn't set up a new configuration or anything. For what it's worth, the breakpoint is after that line.

Comment: Are you compiling in eclipse? If not, make sure your source symbols are in sync with the compiled code.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing everything in eclipse.

Comment: @iiacp Restart your eclipse and then debug it. Or Make a new class with the same code and then put your debug point after this line.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your breakpoint? 
It makes perfect sense if it's in the line of `answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();`. When you set a breakpoint and eclipse breaks on it, everything you see is what you are *before* the execution of that line.